# What is meant by $f(z)\in A(Z-\text{plane})$ here

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, plane-geometry

> $$
> \text { Let } f(z)=x^{2}+a x y+b y^{2}+i\left(c x^{2}+d x y+y^{2}\right) \in A(Z \text { -plane }), \text { find } a, b, c, d \text { . }
> $$

If we put $$a=2,b=1,c=1,d=2$$
Then we get...
$$f(z)=(x+y)^2(1+i)=X+iY$$

Is that what they want?

Can you please tell me ?? I have one more doubt related to it..but maybe after this it may get already cleared

Comment: We probably need more context. It is hard to tell from what you have given us.

Comment: You mean the question in the image is not sufficient? @ThomasAndrews ?

Comment: I guess you have to check the Cauchy Riemann equations and I also guess $A(Z-plane)$ is the set of all analytic functions in the Z-plane.

Comment: Yeah you may sound right :) let me try that and let me check whether I obtain something relevant or not.